# How does Optional.map() exactly works?

Tags: java, option-type

According to [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-), Optional.map() returns an Optional.

In the following snippet:

```
public String getName(Long tpUserId) {
    Optional<TpUser> selectedTpUser = tpUserRepo.findById(tpUserId);
    return selectedTpUser.map(user -> user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getSurName())
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No user found for this id"));
  }
```

it looks like, I want to return a String but I get an Optional. Nevertheless there is no compile error. Why?

Comment: Because `.orElseThrow()` returns `String` and not `Optional<String>`. You're chaining the `.map()` method, which is the way it's meant to be used.

Comment: It returns a `String`. The first step (`map(...)`) maps the `Optional<User>` to an `Optional<String>`. The second step (`orElseThrow(...)`) unwraps the `Optional<String>`, thus returning a `String`. --- You can find the source code of `Optional::map` [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Optional.java#l210).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole chain of operations returns a `String`:

- The first step ([`map(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#map(java.util.function.Function))) maps the `Optional<User>` to an `Optional<String>`.
- The second step ([`orElseThrow(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow(java.util.function.Supplier))) unwraps the `Optional<String>`, thus returning a `String` (or throwing an `IllegalArgumentException`, if empty).

We can find the source code of `Optional::map` [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Optional.java#l210).

Answer (score 4):

You are totally correct.  The `map()` method returns an Optional, and I applaud your use of the javadoc.  The difference here is that you then invoke the `orElseThrow()` method *on that Optional* that `map()` returned.  If you refer to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-) for `orElseThrow()`, you will see that it returns "the present value [of the Optional]".  In this case, that is a String.

Comment: I foccussed on the first part, my bad!